# free objects book recommendation

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra, universal-property

I have huge problems in understanding free objects, e.g. why $\mathbb{Q}$ is free over the empty set and in which category or how a free object over two elements would look like etc.

So I thought someone could recommend a book with lots of examples and good explanations. What helped you to understand that?

Comment: It is to my understanding that these types of questions (opinion based questions) are frowned upon here on the stack exchange. This is certainly an excellent question and will be useful to users, but I'm unsure if you'll find an adequate answer on the stack exchange as your question will likely be closed.

Comment: I guess I can't categorically say there are no such books, but I would be surprised if there were an entire book dedicated to what amounts to a single definition in a regular algebra book.

Comment: I would imagine the largest collection on that one narrow topic in one bundle is going to be [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object)

Comment: Free objects are "the biggest thing you can generate" given the constraints of the category.  In the category of $\mathbb Q$ algebras, $\mathbb Q$ is generated by the emptyset, $\mathbb Q[x]$ is the free algebra on one generator, $\mathbb Q [x,y]$ is the free algebra on two generators and so on.  In terms of $\mathbb Q$ modules, $\{0\}$ is the free one generated by the emptyset, $\mathbb Q$ is the free one on one generator, $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ is the free one one two generators and so on...

Comment: @Kraig I'm sorry I just thought because I have absolutely no idea about it, it's better to ask for book.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks. Could you explain why it is the empty set and how can I see that?

Comment: @maria95 I have no problem with it at all, it's just to my understanding that these kinds of questions are generally closed.

Comment: @maria95 it’s the largest $\mathbb  Q $ algebra you can make with zero extra generators

Comment: You may also want to consider just learning category theory.

Comment: @rschwieb So have I understood that right that the intuition / idea behind the free objects is to find a relatively small set in order to produce the biggest possible objects. In case of $\mathbb{Q}$ algebras there are constant operations and others which suffice to produce $\mathbb{Q}$. For example the empty set would not be enough for ($\mathbb{N}, f$) in the category of algebras with one unary operation, where f is the successor operator, because at least one element is needed to generate $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: And yes a book about category theory is fine too, but with a major chapter on free objects. So suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @maria95 Yes, free objects solve a sort of optimization problem.  More generally that's the idea behind [all universal properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property), and free objects are just one example.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks, that helped me a lot! :)